# How to declaratively enforce compatibility of types?

Tags: typescript

I would like to enforce a (compile-time) constraint that a variable of type `T2` be assignable to a variable of type `T1`.

If I have a value (`t2`) of type `T2` then I can do the following:

```
const t1: T1 = t2;
```

Is there a better way to do this ? Preferably without having to create additional runtime entities.

---

I don't define either of these types directly in my application so I can not make one the superclass of other.

Comment: `T2 extends T1`?

Comment: No. They have no shared lineage.

Comment: Could you please [edit] to clarify what exactly you're trying to do, then?

Comment: *They have no shared lineage.*: but they should have: that's how you will be able to refer to a T1 or a T2 as a CommonInterface or CommonSuperClass, and not care whether it's a T1 or a T2.

Comment: In my use case T2 is a generated model type (from mobx-state-tree) and T1 is an interface from a third party library. I would like to enforce that they stay in sync.

I can not enforce any shared lineage because I don't define either of these classes.

Comment: lineage is irrelevant, types in [typescript are structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html). The way you do it in the question is **the** way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a witness that will give you a compile error if `T2` is not assignable to `T1` without emitting anything at runtime?  Sure, you can define something like this:

```
type ExtendsWitness<U extends T, T> = U
```

and use it like this:

```
type T2Witness = ExtendsWitness<T2, T1>
```

If `T2` is assignable to `T1`, you will get no errors.  Otherwise, you will get an error on the first type argument to `ExtendsWitness` saying that `T2` does not meet the constraint `T1`.

---

Here's an example with some concrete types:

```
interface Super {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}

interface GoodSub {
  foo: 'a';
  bar: 3;
  baz: boolean;
}

type GoodWitness = ExtendsWitness<GoodSub, Super> // okay
```

Notice that `GoodSub` is not defined in terms of `Super`, but `GoodSub` is witnessed by the compiler to be a subtype of `Super` nonetheless.  Here's an example of a bad subtype:

```
interface BadSub {
  foo: string;
  baz: boolean;
}

type BadWitness = ExtendsWitness<BadSub, Super> // error
```

The compiler cannot witness that `BadSub` is a subtype of `Super`, and the error tells you exactly what the problem is: `Type 'BadSub' does not satisfy the constraint 'Super'. Property 'bar' is missing in type 'BadSub'.`

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: This is really brilliant. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the thing you want is achievable as is. Sorry for the stupid sentence, but as long as you cannot define the relativity of the types => you cannot define relativity of the types.

However, you still have the following options:

1. Use `any` type to simply assign the values

   ```
   const t1: T1 = <any>t2;
   const t3: T2 = <any>t1;`
   ```
2. Similar solution with a caster function:

   ```
   function toT1(t: T2): T1 {
       return <any>t;
   } 

   const t1 = toT1(t2);
   ```

   Advantage is that you don't need to define t1 type.
3. Create a type that merges two types into one

   ```
   type T3 = T1 | T2;

   const t1: T3 = t2;
   ```

   This solves the problem with assignment but could lead to some problems with the entities that are already bound to those T1 and T2. This can be used situationally depending on the needs
4. Create a custom type guard:

   ```
   interface T1 { a: any; }

   interface T2 { b: any; }

   function isT1(t: T1 | T2): t is T1 {
       return true;
   }

   const t2: T2 = { b: 1 };
   const t1: T1 = isT1(t2) ? t2 : null;
   ```

   This returns true all the time so you can assign your variable to `t1` without any problem. However this is still ugly.

I would go with a way number 1. It is simple and fully covers your needs. Over engineering is also bad.